# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction bei deployment on Jboss EAP and JDK 1.8

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am running a simple application using Hibernate, MySQL und JBoss EAP 7.3.5.GA. I want to use JTA as hibernate current session context class.

**standalone.xml**

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/MysqlXADS" pool-name="MysqlXADS">
                <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutorialdb?serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <driver>mysqlXA</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>####</user-name>
                    <password>####</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </xa-datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysqlXA" module="com.mysql.jdbc">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.jdbc">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

**WebListener**

```
@WebListener
```

public class HibernateSessionFactoryListener implements ServletContextListener {

```
public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateSessionFactoryListener.class);
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactoryObj = (SessionFactory) servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getAttribute("SessionFactory");
    if(sessionFactoryObj != null && !sessionFactoryObj.isClosed()){
        logger.info("Closing Session Factory Object!");
        sessionFactoryObj.close();
    }
    logger.info("Hibernate Session Factory Object Released!");
}

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    // Creating Configuration Instance & Passing Hibernate Configuration File
    Configuration configObj = new Configuration();
    configObj.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    // Since Hibernate Version 4.x, Service Registry Is Being Used
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistryObj = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configObj.getProperties()).build(); 

    // Creating Hibernate Session Factory Instance
    SessionFactory factoryObj = configObj.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryObj);

    // Saving Hibernate Session Factory Object In The Request Scope
    servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("SessionFactory", factoryObj);
    logger.info("Hibernate Session Factory Configured Successfully!");
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name="employee", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id"})})
public class Employee {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true, length=11)
private int empId;

@Column(name="name", length=20, nullable=true)
private String empName;

@Column(name="role", length=20, nullable=true)
private String empRole;

@Column(name="insert_time", nullable=true)
private Date createdDate;
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
```

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      java:jboss/MysqlXADS
      true

```
  <!-- SQL Dialect -->
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

  <!-- Specifying Session Context -->
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup.class</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>


  <!-- Mapping With Model Class Containing Annotations -->
  <mapping class="com.jcg.hibernate.jndi.model.Employee" />
```

I couldn't find any help here. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: how are you deploying?manual or IDE?

Comment: I am deploying manually

Comment: @GvSharma: Any idea? Have you deployed using IDE?

Comment: If you are deploying to JBoss EAP you don't need to build the SessionFactory manually. You can just inject it with `@PersistenceUnit` if you need it or the transaction scoped EntityManager/Session with `@PersistenceContext`